# SQL Server or Java is adding an extra hour to timestamp queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm working on a Java project with few classmates handling SQL database information, for some reason any time my computer makes a timestamp query to the server the time returned always has an hour added to it. This issue is unique to my computer and attempt to correct it, either with magic numbers or programmatically, cause everyone else's code to break.

We have been working on this project for 3 - 4 weeks, and it has been an issue from day one. If I turn off the Daylight Saving time, the time will be correct, but I know that is not viable a permanent solution. The tests still fail this morning after DST.

Software details
Java -version
openJDK version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10, mixed mode, sharing)
javac 17.0.6

NetBeans:   Apache NetBeans IDE 15
Java:       17.0.6; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.6+10-LTS
Runtime:    OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17.0.6+10-LTS
System:     Windows 11 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

MySQL
Client:     Version 14.14 Distrib 5.7.40 for Win64(x86_64)
Server:     Version 5.7.40
Workbench:  Version 8.0.31 build 22355049 CE (64 bits)
Connector J:    Version 8.0.31

All of us are in the same time zone and have identical time settings, Central -6:00, set time automatically, and adjust for dst. The MySQL time zone queries return the correct time zone and initially the MySQL @@SESSION.time_zone returned -05:00, in spite of being set to Central Time Zone. Using the administrative options of MySQL Workbench I manually set the time_zone to -06:00, which didn't help. When I used the command SQL command SET time_zone = '-06:00'; it changed the @@SESSION.time_zone to -06:00 but the outputs results remained the same. TimeZone.getDefault() on all of out systems returns the same results so there was no useful information in there.

I'm not sure what the cause is or how to fix it. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Data, settings, output

[image: 1]

Comment: What's date data type of the table column or query? What's the data type of the Java object?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how long have you been seeing this issue?  If, for example, the code was working for everyone, and then when you tried it today after 2AM, your issue could be as simple as daylight savings time just starting this morning.

Comment: It's time to learn about Epoch and timezones, TimeZone.getDefault(); and see which timezone you're using

Comment: @Karim `TimeZone` was supplanted years ago by `ZoneId`.

Comment: @Basil Bourque still doesn't change the fact you can still get the default value of timezone used in your JVM when you call TimeZone.getDefault()

Comment: from the Doc: Gets the default TimeZone of the Java virtual machine. If the cached default TimeZone is available, its clone is returned. Otherwise, the method takes the following steps to determine the default time zone. Use the user.timezone property value as the default time zone ID if it's available.
Detect the platform time zone ID. The source of the platform time zone and ID mapping may vary with implementation.
Use GMT as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is unknown.

Comment: @Karim You indeed can. We are many who recommend using the modern way and ignoring the outdated class for the sake of the good habit and because the `TimeZone` class is poorly designed and has some nasty surprises.

Comment: @TheImpaler The datatype in SQL is a timestamp datatype and the Java query converts the timestamp to a LocalDateTime. However, if I System.out.println( [SQL RETURN] ), without converting, the server is sending back the timestamp with the extra hour.

Comment: @JosiahHudson Not a dumb question at all. We have been working on this project for 3 - 4 weeks and it has been an issue from day one. I'm sorry I didnt say in the original post but if I turn off the Day Light Saving time the time will be correct but I know that is not viable a permanent solution. However, the tests still fail this morning after DST.

Comment: ZoneID.systemDefault() = America/Chicago
TimeZone.getDefault() = util.calendar.ZoneInfo
[id="America/Chicago", offset=-21600000, dstSavings=3600000, useDaylight=true, transitions=235, lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Chicago, offset=-21600000, dstSavings=3600000, useDaylight=true, startYear=0, startMode=3, startMonth=2, startDay=8, startDayOfWeek=1, startTime=7200000, startTimeMode=0, endMode=3 endMonth=10, endDay=1, endDayOfWeek=1, endTime=7200000, endTimeMode=0 ] ]

All these settings are identical on all systems and SQL is using America/Chicago.